# How to set filetype to PKGBUILD when the filename is PKGBUILD?

Tags: filetype

I want vim to automatically set the filetype to PKGBUILD when I am editing files that are named "PKGBUILD".  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the following autocmd in your vimrc :

```
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile PKGBUILD set filetype=PKGBUILD
```

And to make sure the autocmd is not duplicated every time your vimrc is sourced, you could wrap it into an augroup and empty the latter at the beginning (`autocmd!`):

```
augroup pkgbuild
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile PKGBUILD set filetype=PKGBUILD
augroup END
```

`BufRead` and `BufNewFile` are 2 possible events which will trigger, for a buffer whose name is `PKGBUILD`, the command: `set filetype=PKGBUILD`

For more information, see:

```
:help autocmd
:help autocmd-events
:help augroup
```

Comment: You should probably move the "edit" to the top of the post. :D

Comment: Your new edit implies that the *augroup* brings "no advantage", which is not correct. I'd be tempted just to remove the older version of the autocmd entirely.